# Populate + Aggregate on Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose (5.x.x) with the populate function to populate an array (meals) with refs. 
 Within that array I need to multiply a price (result of the populate) and a quantity (part of the base Schema).

My populate result as below:

```
{
    "_id": "5bea354235711482876f8fa8",
    "meals": [
        {
            "meal": {
                "_id": "5be93c7074488c77b10fba00",
                "name": "Chicken Nuggets",
                "price": 3
            },
            "quantity": 12
        },
        {
            "meal": {
                "_id": "5be93c9274488c77b10fba01",
                "name": "Beef Burger",
                "price": 6
            },
            "quantity": 4
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

The goal would be to add a "total price" within this result set but I can't find any elegant way to do so.
 I'd like to avoid manipulating data outside of the query.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: You cannot mix `populate()` and `aggregate()`. There is instead [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to use in an aggregation pipeline **instead** of calling `populate()` altogether. No code here, and without it we can only point you to generic examples.

Comment: Alternately, just do the `populate()` with `lean()` and manipulate the result object in JavaScript code. A simple [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over the array content should do the job.

Comment: I should have mentioned I would like to achieve this through mongodb rather that manipulating in Javascript. I find the code alternative not so elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there's a couple of ways to do this as mentioned.

### Using $lookup

You basically want to get the "related" data from the other collection and "merge" that with the existing array items. You cannot actually just "target" the existing array since [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) cannot do that, but it can write *another* array and then you can "merge" them together:

```
let result1 = await Order.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Meal.collection.name,
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "localField": "meals.meal",
    "as": "mealitems"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "meals": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$meals",
        "in": {
          "meal": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$mealitems",
              { "$indexOfArray": [ "$mealitems._id", "$$this.meal" ] }
            ]
          },
          "quantity": "$$this.quantity",
          "totalPrice": {
            "$multiply": [
              { "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$mealitems.price",
                { "$indexOfArray": [ "$mealitems._id", "$$this.meal" ] }
              ]},
              "$$this.quantity"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "totalOrder": {
      "$sum": "$meals.totalPrice"
    }
  }}
]);
```

That basically produces another array `"mealitems"` as the result of `$lookup` and then uses [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) in order to process through the original document array and *transpose* the returned content array items back into the structure for each item.

You do that in combination with [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) and [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) to find the matched items to *transpose* here.

There is also some "math" for the other computed elements using [`$multiply`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/), and even an additional [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage using [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to "add those up" to give an overall "order total" for the document.

You "could" just do all that math in the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage ( which is used because we don't want the `"mealitems"` content. But that's a little more involved and you probably want to use [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) for the array matching so you don't repeat your code so much.

You can even use the "sub-pipeline" form of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) if you really want to. Instead of using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) as the operations to alter the returned documents are done "inside" the returned array *before* the results are returned, by transposing the initial document array into the result documents via it's `let` argument:

```
// Aggregate with $lookup - sub-pipeline
let result2 = await Order.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Meal.collection.name,
    "let": { "meals": "$meals" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": {
          "$in": [ "$_id", "$$meals.meal" ]
        }
      }},
      { "$replaceRoot": {
        "newRoot": {
          "meal": "$$ROOT",
          "quantity": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$$meals.quantity",
              { "$indexOfArray": [ "$$meals.meal", "$_id" ] }
            ]
          },
          "totalPrice": {
            "$multiply": [
              { "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$$meals.quantity",
                { "$indexOfArray": [ "$$meals.meal", "$_id" ] }
              ]},
              "$price"
            ]
          }
        }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "meals"
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "totalOrder": {
      "$sum": "$meals.totalPrice"
    }
  }}
]);
```

In either form, that's basically an allegory for what `populate()` is doing under the hood by "merging" the content, but of course that uses separate database requests where the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation is just **one** request.

### Using populate()

Alternately you can just manipulate the resulting structure in JavaScript. It's already there, and all you really need is the `lean()` in order to be able to alter the resulting objects:

```
// Populate and manipulate
let result3 = await Order.find().populate('meals.meal').lean();

result3 = result3.map(r =>
  ({
      ...r,
      meals: r.meals.map( m =>
        ({
          ...m,
          totalPrice: m.meal.price * m.quantity
        })
      ),
      totalOrder: r.meals.reduce((o, m) =>
        o + (m.meal.price * m.quantity), 0
      )
  })
);
```

It looks pretty simple and is basically the same thing, with the exceptions that the "merging" was already done for you and that of course this is **two** requests to the server in order to return all the data.

---

As a reproducible full listing:

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Connection
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/menu';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true };

// Sensible defaults
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('debug', true);

// Schema defs

const mealSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  price: Number
});

const orderSchema = new Schema({
  meals: [
    {
      meal: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Meal' },
      quantity: Number
    }
  ]
});

const Meal = mongoose.model('Meal', mealSchema);
const Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);

// log helper
const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

// main
(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, opts);

    // clean models
    await Promise.all(
      Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.deleteMany())
    );

    // Set up data

    let [Chicken, Beef] = await Meal.insertMany(
      [
        { name: "Chicken Nuggets", price: 3 },
        { name: "Beef Burger", price: 6 }
      ]
    );

    let order = await Order.create({
      meals: [
        { meal: Chicken, quantity: 12 },
        { meal: Beef, quantity: 4 }
      ]
    });


    // Aggregate with $lookup - traditional
    let result1 = await Order.aggregate([
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": Meal.collection.name,
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "localField": "meals.meal",
        "as": "mealitems"
      }},
      { "$project": {
        "meals": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$meals",
            "in": {
              "meal": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$mealitems",
                  { "$indexOfArray": [ "$mealitems._id", "$$this.meal" ] }
                ]
              },
              "quantity": "$$this.quantity",
              "totalPrice": {
                "$multiply": [
                  { "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$mealitems.price",
                    { "$indexOfArray": [ "$mealitems._id", "$$this.meal" ] }
                  ]},
                  "$$this.quantity"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }},
      { "$addFields": {
        "totalOrder": {
          "$sum": "$meals.totalPrice"
        }
      }}
    ]);
    log(result1);

    // Aggregate with $lookup - sub-pipeline
    let result2 = await Order.aggregate([
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": Meal.collection.name,
        "let": { "meals": "$meals" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$in": [ "$_id", "$$meals.meal" ]
            }
          }},
          { "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": {
              "meal": "$$ROOT",
              "quantity": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$$meals.quantity",
                  { "$indexOfArray": [ "$$meals.meal", "$_id" ] }
                ]
              },
              "totalPrice": {
                "$multiply": [
                  { "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$$meals.quantity",
                    { "$indexOfArray": [ "$$meals.meal", "$_id" ] }
                  ]},
                  "$price"
                ]
              }
            }
          }}
        ],
        "as": "meals"
      }},
      { "$addFields": {
        "totalOrder": {
          "$sum": "$meals.totalPrice"
        }
      }}
    ]);
    log(result2);

    // Populate and manipulate
    let result3 = await Order.find().populate('meals.meal').lean();

    result3 = result3.map(r =>
      ({
          ...r,
          meals: r.meals.map( m =>
            ({
              ...m,
              totalPrice: m.meal.price * m.quantity
            })
          ),
          totalOrder: r.meals.reduce((o, m) =>
            o + (m.meal.price * m.quantity), 0
          )
      })
    );

    log(result3);

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }

})()
```

Which returns results like:

```
Mongoose: meals.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: orders.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: meals.insertMany([ { _id: 5bea4c8f6edcd22d385a13bf, name: 'Chicken Nuggets', price: 3, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5bea4c8f6edcd22d385a13c0, name: 'Beef Burger', price: 6, __v: 0 } ], {})
Mongoose: orders.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("5bea4c8f6edcd22d385a13c1"), meals: [ { _id: ObjectId("5bea4c8f6edcd22d385a13c3"), meal: ObjectId("5bea4c8f6edcd22d385a13bf"), quantity: 12 }, { _id: ObjectId("5bea4c8f6edcd22d385a13c2"), meal: ObjectId("5bea4c8f6edcd22d385a13c0"), quantity: 4 } ], __v: 0 })
Mongoose: orders.aggregate([ { '$lookup': { from: 'meals', foreignField: '_id', localField: 'meals.meal', as: 'mealitems' } }, { '$project': { meals: { '$map': { input: '$meals', in: { meal: { '$arrayElemAt': [ '$mealitems', { '$indexOfArray': [ '$mealitems._id', '$$this.meal' ] } ] }, quantity: '$$this.quantity', totalPrice: { '$multiply': [ { '$arrayElemAt': [ '$mealitems.price', { '$indexOfArray': [Array] } ] }, '$$this.quantity' ] } } } } } }, { '$addFields': { totalOrder: { '$sum': '$meals.totalPrice' } } } ], {})
[
  {
    "_id": "5bea4c8f6edcd22d385a13c1",
    "meals": [
      {
        "meal": {
          "_id": "5bea4c8f6edcd22d385a13bf",
          "name": "Chicken Nuggets",
          "price": 3,
          "__v": 0
        },
        "quantity": 12,
        "totalPrice": 36
      },
      {
        "meal": {
          "_id": "5bea4c8f6edcd22d385a13c0",
          "name": "Beef Burger",
          "price": 6,
          "__v": 0
        },
        "quantity": 4,
        "totalPrice": 24
      }
    ],
    "totalOrder": 60
  }
]
Mongoose: orders.aggregate([ { '$lookup': { from: 'meals', let: { meals: '$meals' }, pipeline: [ { '$match': { '$expr': { '$in': [ '$_id', '$$meals.meal' ] } } }, { '$replaceRoot': { newRoot: { meal: '$$ROOT', quantity: { '$arrayElemAt': [ '$$meals.quantity', { '$indexOfArray': [ '$$meals.meal', '$_id' ] } ] }, totalPrice: { '$multiply': [ { '$arrayElemAt': [ '$$meals.quantity', [Object] ] }, '$price' ] } } } } ], as: 'meals' } }, { '$addFields': { totalOrder: { '$sum': '$meals.totalPrice' } } } ], {})
[
  {
    "_id": "5bea4c8f6edcd22d385a13c1",
    "meals": [
      {
        "meal": {
          "_id": "5bea4c8f6edcd22d385a13bf",
          "name": "Chicken Nuggets",
          "price": 3,
          "__v": 0
        },
        "quantity": 12,
        "totalPrice": 36
      },
      {
        "meal": {
          "_id": "5bea4c8f6edcd22d385a13c0",
          "name": "Beef Burger",
          "price": 6,
          "__v": 0
        },
        "quantity": 4,
        "totalPrice": 24
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0,
    "totalOrder": 60
  }
]
Mongoose: orders.find({}, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: meals.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("5bea4c8f6edcd22d385a13bf"), ObjectId("5bea4c8f6edcd22d385a13c0") ] } }, { projection: {} })
[
  {
    "_id": "5bea4c8f6edcd22d385a13c1",
    "meals": [
      {
        "_id": "5bea4c8f6edcd22d385a13c3",
        "meal": {
          "_id": "5bea4c8f6edcd22d385a13bf",
          "name": "Chicken Nuggets",
          "price": 3,
          "__v": 0
        },
        "quantity": 12,
        "totalPrice": 36
      },
      {
        "_id": "5bea4c8f6edcd22d385a13c2",
        "meal": {
          "_id": "5bea4c8f6edcd22d385a13c0",
          "name": "Beef Burger",
          "price": 6,
          "__v": 0
        },
        "quantity": 4,
        "totalPrice": 24
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0,
    "totalOrder": 60
  }
]
```

Comment: Absolutely perfectly clear answer. Thanks a lot for all the details.